# DROP a not nullable column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I use ORACLE and i know that you cannot DROP a column which has a not null constraint.

You have to change it first to be nullable and then you can drop it.

If the column is not a primary key or foreign key , why cant i just drop it?

Can someone explain the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Show your table structure, you sql query and the error message please.

Comment: "*I know that you cannot DROP a column which has a not null constraint*" - that's plain wrong. From where did you get that? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cae4ea/1

Comment: Ok i might be wrong.So you can drop a not nullable column (which has values inside it) ?

Comment: @raz Yes, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use ORACLE and i know that you cannot DROP a column which has a not null constraint.

No, you are wrong. You can drop a **NOT NULL** column.

> If the column is not a primary key or foreign key , why cant i just drop it?

Yes, you can.

See:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(a number, b varchar2(10) not null);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t(A, b) VALUES(1, 'one');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A B
---------- ----------
         1 one

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN b;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> DESC t;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------
 A                                                  NUMBER

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
         1

SQL>
```